# How can I solve such an inverse Z-transform?

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform

I was going through some old exams and found this question:

> Find the inverse $Z$-transform of $z^{-1/2}$.

I tried using the properties table, but I couldn't find a single useful property that would help me solve this question. I don't have the solution of the past exam, so I would really appreciate a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to note and keep in mind is the $\mathcal{Z}^{-1} \{ z^{-1}\}$ which is $\delta(n-1)$.

Now this is not as straightforward as the case mentioned above, but it's not that difficult of a task either. We will make use of contour integration. The inverse $Z$-transform relation is given by:

\begin{equation}
    x[n] = \frac{1}{2 \pi j} \oint_C X(z) z^{n-1} dz \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Plug in our $X(z) = z^{-1/2}$:

\begin{equation}
    x[n] = \frac{1}{2 \pi j} \oint_C z^{-1/2} z^{n-1} dz \tag{2}
\end{equation}

At this stage we will apply a change of variables as follows:

\begin{align*}
    z &= e^{j\omega}\\
    \frac{dz}{d\omega} &= je^{j\omega}= jz\\
    dz &= je^{j\omega} \; d\omega
\end{align*}

And for the contour, as you may know, the [ROC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) of a Z-transform is considered based on the unit circle. As such, we can take the contour limits from either $0$ to $2\pi$ or from $-\pi$ to $\pi$; it doesn't matter ($\omega$ follows such a path on the circle when integrating counterclockwise). Using the latter limits and the above change of variable, we have:

\begin{equation}
    x[n] = \frac{1}{2 \pi j} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-j\omega/2} e^{j\omega(n-1)} je^{j\omega}\; d\omega \tag{3}
\end{equation}

The $j$'s cancel and so does $e^{j\omega}$ with $e^{-j\omega}$, leaving us with the following:

\begin{equation}
    x[n] = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-j\omega/2} e^{j\omega n} \; d\omega \tag{4}
\end{equation}

Does it look familiar? This is nothing, but the inverse [DTFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform) of $e^{-j\omega/2}$.

Let's solve the integral:

\begin{equation}
   \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{j(n-\frac12)\omega} \; d\omega \tag{5}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   \frac{1}{2 \pi} \left(\frac{e^{j(n-\frac12)\omega}}{j(n-\frac12)} \right)\bigg\rvert_{-\pi}^{\pi} \tag{6}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   \frac{e^{j(n-\frac12)\pi} - e^{-j(n-\frac12)\pi}}{2 \pi j(n-\frac12)} \tag{7}
\end{equation}

Now we will make use of the identity:

\begin{align*}
    \sin(\theta) = \frac{e^{j\theta} - e^{-j\theta}}{2j}
\end{align*}

In our case, this $\theta$ is just $\pi(n-\frac12)$ and we get:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{\sin(\pi(n-\frac12))}{\pi(n-\frac12)} \tag{8}
\end{equation}

as our final answer!

I mentioned the $\mathcal{Z}^{-1} \{ z^{-1}\}$ just to motivate what I think the reason behind asking the question was. The inverse transform of a single delay is just a shifted impulse, but what if that delay was fractional?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have learned contour integration in my complex analysis course but never knew it could be used in this context. May I ask how you got the relation in $(1)$?

Comment: Wonderful answer. Just just one question, is this change of variables always valid? Indeed, such a change simplified it ridiculously as we avoid the contour integral and deal with an ordinary integral instead.

Comment: @RubemPacelli The change comes from the relation between the Z-Transform and DTFT.

Comment: What is *"[C.O.V.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COV)"*? [Calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations)?

Comment: "[...] the ROC of a Z-transform is considered based on the unit circle." I'm not sure what you're trying to say here. That's also where the problem of this answer lies. There is no annulus $r<|z|<R$ for which the corresponding series converges. That's why we should say that only the IDTFT exists, but not the inverse Z-transform.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Change Of Variable. Should have written it clearly, my bad!

Comment: @MattL. Yes, I am aware of that. My question is if this change is always valid. I was used to perform the inverse z-transform via partial fraction decomposition, so I am a little bit unsure if your strategy is always valid.

Answer (score 6):

The correct answer to the question

> What is the inverse $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $F(z)=z^{-\frac12}?$

is

> $F(z)=z^{-\frac12}$ is not a valid $\mathcal{Z}$-transform, hence its inverse transform doesn't exist.

For $F(z)$ to be a valid $\mathcal{Z}$-transform, its Laurent series about $z_0=0$ must exist. However, for the given function, $z_0=0$ is a branch point and there is no annulus $r_1<|z|<r_2$ for which $F(z)$ is analytic. Consequently, the inverse $\mathcal{Z}$-transform doesn't exist. In other words, there is no series of the form

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_nz^{-n}$$

which converges uniformly to the function $F(z)=z^{-\frac12}$ in some annulus  $r_1<|z|<r_2$.

The result derived in [Ahson Yousef's answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/87855/4298) is the inverse discrete-time Fourier transform (IDTFT) of $F(e^{j\omega})=e^{-j\omega /2}$.

In this example the situation is similar to the inverse transformation of a rectangular function or of a Dirac delta impulse in the frequency domain, in the sense that in these cases only the IDTFT exists, but not the inverse $\mathcal{Z}$-transform. The corresponding series only converge on the unit circle $|z|=1$.

Comment: Fixed the missing +1 :-).