# Unwindowed STFT of sine, closed form solution and insights (sliding FFT)

Tags: discrete-signals, dft, continuous-signals, stft

I seek to calculate, mathematically, the unwindowed Short-Time Fourier Transform of

$$
\cos(2\pi f t + \phi)
$$

i.e. any arbitrary real-valued sine: any frequency, duration, phase shift, and number of samples. The expression should reflect practical use, in that it's how we'd sample a sine in code. In effect, something like *(MATLAB)*

```matlab
t = [0:N-1] * sampling_period
x = cos(2*pi * f * t + phi)
closed_form(N, f, phi, sampling_period, nfft, hop_size) == stft(x, nfft, hop_size)
```

Answers can merely specify the steps required to perform this calculation, but it should be enough such that, the guided solution, expressed in code, validates against `stft(x)`.

Once the solution is obtained, can it be used to reveal something new, or confirm known facts (e.g. symmetry, decay behavior)? Optionally, the result should be code-validated.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\boxed{
\begin{align}
& \texttt{STFT}_{M, H}\{\cos(2\pi f t + \phi)\}_{f(M/N)\notin\mathbb{Z}}[k, \tau] = \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad \sin(\pi f_M)
 \left(
   \frac{U_\tau e^{j2\pi k/M} - V_\tau}
   {\cos(2\pi k/M) - \cos(2\pi f_M/M)}
  \right) \\
& U_\tau = \sin(\pi f_M + \phi_\tau),\\
& V_\tau = \sin(\pi f_M + \phi_\tau - 2\pi f_M/M),\\
& \phi_\tau = \phi + 2\pi (f_M/M)H\tau,\ f_M = f(M/N).
 \\
& \qquad H = \text{hop size},\ 
         M = \text{segment size} = \texttt{nfft},\ 
         N = \text{signal size} \\
& \qquad \texttt{STFT}_{M, H}\{x(t)\}[k, \tau] = 
  \texttt{DFT}\{x(t + \tau H/N)_{:M}\}[k] \\
& \qquad  x(s)_{:M} = x(s_{:M}),\ s_{:M} = [s[0], s[1], ..., s[M - 1]] \\
& \qquad \tau, H\in \mathbb{Z};
  \ 0 \leq \tau \leq \lfloor{(N - M)/H\rfloor} + 1;
  \ 1 \leq H \leq N;\ M \leq N \\
& \qquad t = (1/N)[0, 1, ..., N - 1]
\end{align}
}
$$

and (with same $t$ & others),

$$
\boxed{
\begin{align}
& \texttt{STFT}_{M, H}\{\cos(2\pi f t + \phi)\}_{f(M/N)\in\mathbb{Z}}[k, \tau] = \\
 & \qquad \frac{M}{2}\left(e^{j\phi_\tau} \delta [(k - f_M)_M] + 
         e^{-j\phi_\tau}\delta [(k + f_M)_M]\right) \\
& (z)_M = z\ \text{mod}\ M
\end{align}
}
$$

This implements `'valid'`-mode (unpadded / don't hop outside of `x`) STFT, or also (with $N$ modified) STFT of a proper (e.g. `'reflect'`-) padding of a sine that is within one sample of whole number of cycles.

Except for being precise on discrete vs continuous units, the result follows trivially from DFT of sine:

1. We just seek $\texttt{DFT}\{\cos(2\pi f(t + \tau) + \phi)\}$. Equating to $\texttt{DFT}\{\cos(2\pi f t + \phi_\tau)\}$ and solving for $\phi_\tau$ yields $\phi_\tau = \phi + 2\pi f\tau$. Instead of just $\tau$, we need $\tau/N$ so that $\tau$ is integer ($/N$ per how $t$'s defined) and hence refers to shift in samples and is a valid array index. Finally, accounting for hop brings us to $\tau H/N$. Replace $\phi$ with $\phi_\tau$ in the sine solution.
2. Recall that shorter DFT "sees" lower $f$ (see "Understanding SR vs Duration" [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/88389/50076)). So, replace $f$ with $f_M = f(M/N)$ in sine solution.
3. Replace $N$ with $M$ in sine solution (we're taking $M$-point DFTs)
4. Per 2, DFT's "integer $f$" is when $f(M/N)$ is integer, reproducing integer-$f$ sine DFT.

All other stuff is to exactly match STFT as we'd compute it:

- $H$, in math sense, is same as plugging in different $\tau$.
- Bounds on $\tau$ and $M$ make it `'valid'`, and on $H$ make it invertible.
- $s_{:M}$ stuff is a strictly correct way of saying "$M$-point DFT" without leaving $t$'s bounds.

*For clarity*: recall what $t$ is, and let $\tau = 1$, $H=2$, so now we're looking at the cosine at $[2, 3, ..., 2 + (M - 1)]$, so $\tau=0$ was `fft(x[:M])` and $\tau=1$ is `fft(x[2:M+2])`.

#### In code (& $t$ offset note)

With `sine_dft`, this becomes the full code (`np = numpy`):

```py
def sine_stft(N, M, H, f, phi):
    assert M <= N and 1 <= H <= N, (N, M, H)
    n_hops = (N - M)//H + 1
    out = np.zeros((M, n_hops), dtype='complex128')

    for tau in range(n_hops):
        phi_tau = phi + 2*np.pi*f*tau*H/N
        out[:, tau] = sine_dft(M, f*M/N, phi_tau)
    return out
```

For $t = [t_0, ...]$, that's `sine_stft(N, M, H, f, phi + 2*pi*f*t[0])` (see "Effects on parameters" [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/88389/50076)).

#### Spectrogram

$$
\boxed{
\begin{align}
& \left|\texttt{STFT}_{M, H}\{\cos(2\pi f t + \phi)\}_{f_M\in\mathbb{Z}, f_M\notin[0, M/2]}[k, \tau]\right| = 
  \frac{M}{2}\big(\delta[(k - f_M)_M] + \delta[(k + f_M)_M]\big) \\
& \left|\texttt{STFT}_{M, H}\{\cos(2\pi f t + \phi)\}_{f_M\notin\mathbb{Z}}[k, \tau]\right| = 
\left|\sin(\pi f_M)\right|
\frac{\sqrt{U_\tau^2 + V_\tau^2 - 2U_\tau V_\tau\cos(2\pi k/M)}}
 {\left|\cos(2\pi k/M) - \cos(2\pi f_M/M)\right|} \\
& U_\tau = \sin(\pi f_M + \phi_\tau),\\
& V_\tau = \sin(\pi f_M + \phi_\tau - 2\pi f_M/M),\\
& \phi_\tau = \phi + 2\pi (f_M/M)H\tau,\ f_M = f(M/N). \\
\end{align}
}
$$

and if we don't exclude the two edge cases,

$$
\boxed{
\begin{align}
& \left|\texttt{STFT}_{M, H}\{\cos(2\pi f t + \phi)\}_{f_M\in\mathbb{Z}}[k, \tau]\right| = \\
&\qquad \frac{M}{2}\sqrt{
\delta[(k - f_M)_M] + \delta[(k + f_M)_M] + 
\delta[(k - f_M)_M] \delta[(k + f_M)_M](2\cos(2\phi_\tau))
} \\
\end{align}
}
$$

This is best interpreted via familiarity with sine DFT modulus, explored in-depth [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/88400/50076).

*(Note, the $U, V$ formulation is fully equivalent to taking modulus of the expression on top of this answer, explained in "Addendum: Original version vs Modified" [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/88421/50076).)*

#### Interpretation

STFT slides a window over input and takes its DFT. Here there's no window, so we're sliding DFT over a sine. This is exactly the same as sliding the sine instead and keeping DFT in same place. The operations are identical, but the interpretations aren't:

- "sliding DFT" is well-understood as, we're inspecting what the input is like over a certain interval, and using the spectrum to describe it - over various such intervals
- "sliding sine" is well-understood as, we're tracking how the spectrum of the sine changes - how it compares with the unshifted sine, what effect shifting is having. This isn't as relevant for the general input - a sine is stationary: fixed frequency and amplitude over time, so all that's changing is what portion of it we're looking at with a finite frame.

As a sine is being shifted in time by $\tau$,

- All imaginary bins are modulated by a sine of frequency $f$ as a function of $\tau$, with modulation amplitude and offset that depends on the sine.
- A given real bin modulated by a sine of frequency $f$ as a function of $\tau$, with modulation amplitude and offset that depends on the sine and the bin.

where "offset" = fixed phase, and "the sine" = original, unshifted $x(t)$. This is tailored to the second perspective, with an important application - see "Application: High SNR contamination" in Sine DFT article. An interpretation per first perspective can also be made, using time-frequency analysis - left to reader.

#### Insights

##### 1. Unwindowed = Ideal for $f(M/N)\in\mathbb{Z}$

The formula doesn't lie, try `N, M, f = 128, 32, 20` with any `H` & others.

##### 2. Unwindowed = Ideal, for parameter retrieval (noiseless)

Since the inverse problem has been solved (see "Application: exact ..." in [original article](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/88365/50076)).

##### 3. Beats near DC & Nyquist

[image]

$f$ is swept logarithmically over $[0.1, N/4]$, then backwards up to $N/2$, with $N, M = 512, 64$ and $\phi=0$.

The beats can be explained by [sine DFT modulus](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/88400/50076) (Ctrl + F "heavily phase-dependent"), where it was found that energy has the greatest $\phi$-dependence for $f$ near DC & Nyquist. Note, the GIF shows sweeping of $f$; sweeping of $\phi$ is the STFT itself (its time axis).

Directly reasoning from sine DFT alone doesn't generalize, however. The general case (any windowing, multi-component and AM-FM signals) is proven with time-frequency analysis: [Why are there beats in spectrogram of sines?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/87086/50076). Indeed, this beating persists for any windowing, and given STFT's time vs frequency symmetries - i.e. involving DFTs along frequency and time ([explanation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/86938/50076)) - studying sine's STFT can reveal things about sine's DFT (which I've not done).

[Full animation](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/assets/16495490/395334ba-d0cb-4f3d-89c9-a96967fd2ea2) ***(epilepsy warning)***

##### 4. Sine Sliding FFT = ratio of frame edge-modulated & -offset roots of unity

An insight from the [DFT sine solution](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/771.php) ("Signal and Roots of Unity Formulation"):

$$
X[k] = \frac{(x[N] - x[0])R_k - (x[N - 1] - x[-1])}{(x[-1] + x[1])/x[0] - (R_k + R_{-k})}
$$

where $R_k = e^{j2\pi k/N}$, and indexing outside of $[0, N-1]$ is of sine's continuation, not circular.

The DFT knows no such thing as "continuation" beyond what it's given, but STFT's frames do. This can interpret, and we can observe, as follows:

1. **Guaranteed imaginary part**: since $x[N] = x[0]$ can't persist for all $\tau$. Exceptions: "all $\tau$" is one $\tau$; $H=M$ and $f_M$ is integer (for certain $\phi$).
2. **Rare $|\texttt{STFT}[:, \tau_0]| = \texttt{STFT}[:, \tau_0]$** (imag=0): since $x[N] = x[0]$ is possible. "$[:, \tau_0]$" means $\forall k$.
3. **Difference of edges controls decay rate**, since it controls the numerator (point 4 [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/88400/50076)).
4. **Difference of edges controls decay behavior of peaks near DC & Nyquist** (point 1 [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/88400/50076))
5. **Ratio of starting points controls peak location & intensity**, since it controls the denominator. It's sum of $x[\pm 1]$ divided by their midpoint.
6. **Difference of edges controls imaginary part** (its strength relative to real part), since $x[N] - x[0]$ controls the only imag term, and the denominator affects real & imag same.
7. **Fully determined by 5 points per frame**, 3 at start and 2 at end, one out-of-frame per edge.

#### Citation

This work can be cited in one or two parts:

> John Muradeli, 2023. Unwindowed STFT of sine, closed form solution and insights (sliding FFT). URL: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/88806/50076

> Cedron Dawg, 2015. DFT Bin Value Formulas for Pure Real Tones. URL: https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/771.php

If must cite only one, cite first.

#### Code validation

Thoroughly validated against `scipy.signal.stft`, available on [Github](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/StackExchangeAnswers/tree/main/SignalProcessing/Q87926%20-%20DFT%20of%20a%20sine%2C%20closed%20form%20solution%20and%20insights).

Note, I validated via `sine_dft`, so the exact LaTeX above wasn't coded and assumes I got all the substitutions right. Also, `sine_dft` follows the original sine solution, while what's presented in this article is modified; they're equivalent, see "Addendum" in original article. I was careful in handling these correctly, but if it matters, double-check.

Animation code exists, can't share at the moment.